# Example and counterexample for Stone's (1977) assumption

Tags: cross-validation, aic

[Stone (1977)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984877?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) considers the problem of the choice of predicting density for $y$ given $x$ from a prescribed class of formal predicting densities $\{f(y|x,\alpha,S), \alpha \in \mathscr{A}\}$ whose members are indexed by the choice parameter $\alpha$. 
He shows that AIC and LOOCV (leave-one-out cross validation) are asymptotically equivalent provided that the following assumption holds:

> The conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ in the distribution $P$
>   is $f(y|x,\theta^*)$ for some unique $\theta^* \in \Theta$, that is,
>   the conventional model $\{f(y|x,\theta),\theta \in \Theta)\}$ is true.

I am having a hard time understanding this formal requirement and using it in applications.

Could anyone illustrate when this assumption holds vs. when it fails by an example and a counterexample?

**References**

- Stone, M. (1977). [An asymptotic equivalence of choice of model by cross‐validation and Akaike's criterion.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984877?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological), 39*(1), 44-47.

Comment: Related question: [Is this a typo in Stone's (1977) paper on asymptotic equivalence between AIC and LOOCV?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407286/).

Comment: Related question: [Equivalence of AIC and LOOCV under mismatched loss functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406430/equivalence-of-aic-and-loocv-under-mismatched-loss-functions).

Answer (score 2):

This simply formalizes the fact that AIC asymptotically picks the correct distribution out of our hat *if it was in the hat in the first place*.

Simply said, if your data come from a $\text{Pois}(\lambda^\ast)$ distribution, and your hat contains all possible Poisson distributions, then you are good. But if your hat only contains Poisson distributions with parameters that differ by at least $\epsilon>0$ from $\lambda^\ast$, then of course you will not get there. (If your hat contains everything *except* the one true value, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\lambda^\ast\}$, then I presume that the asymptotic result still holds, because we can get arbitrarily close to $\lambda^\ast$. But that is not a counterexample to the statement.)

Alternatively, perhaps your data come from a negative binomial distribution, but your hat only contains Poissons. (The other way around probably works again, because we can approximate a Poisson using a negative binomial, by reducing the overdispersion parameter far enough. Again, not a counterexample.)

---

The other part of the statement is uniqueness: there must be only a single parameter $\theta^\ast$ in the hat that gives the true distribution $f(y|x,\theta)$, so we can asymptotically converge to it. The counterexample to uniqueness would be a hat containing a slice of the real plane $\{(\theta,\tau)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0<\theta<\tau\}$, where a parameter vector $(\theta,\tau)$ parameterizes a $\text{Pois}(\tau-\theta)$ distribution. Then of course a single Poisson will be parameterized by many different pairs $(\theta,\tau)$... but they will be indistinguishable, since they all yield the same PMF.

I honestly don't see (yet) how this is important. I would assume that non-uniqueness of $\theta^\ast$ would simply mean that we would approach the solution space arbitrarily closely but might oscillate wildly within it - but this would, again, not make any difference in terms of what we can actually observe, just make the mathematics more opaque.