# What if AIC and BIC suggested 1 lag in my VAR model but that lag is not significant?

Tags: regression, correlation, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

The question is exactly on the title. I am building a VAR model for a specific commodity. The AIC and BIC suggested 1 lag. However, that coefficient in lag 1 is not significant in my model. Can I still forecast using this model or is it justified to add lags? If I add lags, how much lag needs to be significant until the model is considered a good fit?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275861/aic-and-bic-criterion-for-model-selection-how-is-it-used-in-this-paper/275948#275948 demonstrates that it can be possible to "translate" AIC to a hypothesis test, and a fairly liberal one, so that such behavior is possible.

Comment: See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523485/why-is-aic-or-bic-commonly-used-in-model-selections-for-time-series-forecasting