# ISLR Chapter 6 : Choosing the Optimal Model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling, model-selection

I had a question regarding the "choosing the optimal model" section of chapter 6 of ISLR (pg. 232). The book states that

"In order to select the best model with respect to test error, we need to estimate this test error. There are two common approaches:

1. We can indirectly estimate test error by making an adjustment to the training error to account for the bias due to overfitting.
2. We can directly estimate the test error, using either a validation set approach or a cross-validation approach, as discussed in Chapter 5. "

I understand that we can indirectly estimate the test error by adjusting the training error with the utilization of AIC, BIC, Mallows Cp, and adjusted R-squared to account for the fact that training MSE tends to be lower than test MSE .  In addition, we can estimate the test error directly via the validation set and cross-validation to discern the model with the lowest test error from the candidate models garnered from our model selection methods (best subset / forward selection/ backward selection/ hybrid)

As such, given that the methods to directly estimate the test error makes less assumptions and makes a direct estimate of the test error, why would someone ever choose approach 1?  Or is it that these approaches are complementary to one another and so researchers typically use them both during their analyses?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/523506/9330 is related and could be helpful

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/419127/9330 another related post that may help

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414610/9330 one more that you might want to read. I hope those help!

Comment: Some may argue that approach 2 is only valid when you can spare a lot of data for testing, otherwise the results can be very volatile, in such case approach 1 may be preferred.

Comment: Approach 2 often uses quantities derived from approach 1 -- eg, a cost-complexity penalty like AIC, with validation to choose the penalty multiplier rather than to choose a model directly.